# URLConnection didnt return complete content of file

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

My code looks like

```
    URL oracle = new URL(calURL);    
FileWriter overall = new FileWriter("overall.txt");    
    HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

   overall.append("\n"+inputLine);

    }
```

It seems it is returning only half of content .. Not getting the full content

Note : calURL is dynamically generated

Comment: whats the code you are writing inside the while loop?

Comment: Im just dumping the content to txt file.

Comment: Did you debug your code? applying breakpoints before writing it to the file?

Comment: The file size is more than 40 mb. It has lot of lines. It works fine for 60% of content then it coming out of while loop . So I didnt not do debug ,

Comment: Is there an error? Surround the whole operation in a try-catch.

Comment: No error's it succeeds

Comment: Is the content text? Or binary? If binary, you shouldn't be using a Reader. Are you calling readLine() inside the loop? If so, don't. Insufficient information provided so far.

Comment: Please post the code inside the loop. Edit it into your question.

Comment: The line just read had its line terminator at the end, not at the beginning. Are you ever closing the `FileWriter`?

Comment: yes im closing after my while ends.

Comment: You need to post the *complete* code, or at least a complete piece of code that exhibits the problem. Not your guesss as to where the problem might be. You don't know that, or you wouldn't be posting here.

Answer (score -1):

calURL is taking much time to load. Before its my stream starts reading I guess. I included timeout before URL connection it is getting full data now.

Comment: So you got a timeout exception and didn't say so?

Comment: No i didn't get any exception.